# выходить замуж as opposed to быть замужем

Tags: грамматика

I ran across two sentences: Марина вышла замуж за Павла and then Марина замужем недавно.  What is the difference between using вышла замуж as opposed to замужем?  Are they basically synonyms or are there specific contexts in which one is used over the other?

Comment: What may confuse you is the use of **давно / недавно** typical of Russian. These two are often used to tell that some *state* has been there for a long time (давно) or has started only recently (недавно). In a negative sentence "давно" means that some action has not been done for a long time ("Я давно не был дома" means that the last time you were home was long ago: "I haven't been home for a long time").

Answer (score 10):

Generally speaking, `выйти замуж` is  'to marry (about women)', and `быть замужем` is 'to be married (about women).'

> "Марина вышла замуж за Павла." means 'Marina [has] married Pavel.'

This sentence tells us that Marina is (or was) married, and her husband is (or was) Pavel. Note, this sentence is in the past tense, it tells about the fact of Marina's marriage and about her husband, but it gives no information as for whether she is still married.

> "Марина замужем недавно." means 'Marina has been married recently.'

This sentence tells us that Marina *is* married *now*, and it also tells about how long ago the marriage happened. This sentence is in the present tense. You can also specify the name of the husband in this sentence, like this:

> "Марина замужем за Павлом недавно." means 'Marina has been married to Pavel recently.'

Also note, that in the first sentence it is `за` + Accusative case, but in the second one it is `за` + Instrumental case.

Answer (score 3):

Act vs state. "To get married" vs "to be married".